# Pandas Cumulative sum of 2 cumulative columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to add a cumulative column to a pandas df.

Have tried this code but get a NaNs:

```
df['Total_Coins_Bought'] = df.query("side == 'buy'")['amount'].cumsum()
df['Total_Coins_Sold'] = -df.query("side == 'sell'")['amount'].cumsum()

df['Total_Coins'] = df['Total_Coins_Bought']-df['Total_Coins_Sold']
```

Only looking to build the Total_Coins column; the 2 fields Total_Coins_Bought & Total_Coins_Sold are me just trying to build this step by step

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample input dataframe based on expected output.

Comment: I suggest reading [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), then editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df["sign_amount"] = df["amount"] * df["side"].map({"buy": +1, "sell": -1})
df["total_coins"] = df["sign_amount"].cumsum()
```

Basically, I add a `sign_amount` column, which is identical to the `amount` column, but multiplied by +1 if `side` is "buy", and multiplied by -1 if `side` is "sell".
The `cumsum` of `sign_amount` column should be your desired outcome.

Comment: I agree that the original question was not reproducible, but I think I managed to guess the structure of the DataFrame from the picture.